# Non-existent value appears in R table() count

Tags: r

How does something I have deleted show up as having zero occurrences in `table()`?

```
> load("matmob.data.Rdata") # get chess game data
> table(matmob.data$result) # show game results

    0-1     1-0 1/2-1/2       * 
 468439  620745  607423      58 
> # Now delete unknown results (i.e. result=="*")
> matmob.data <- matmob.data[matmob.data$result != "*", ]
> table(matmob.data$result) # So how does * still show up???

    0-1     1-0 1/2-1/2       * 
 468439  620745  607423       0
```

I suspect this weirdness is the cause of an error in the `qda()` function from the `MASS` package:

> "some group is too small for 'qda'".

Answer (score 2):

`table` is splitting based on the levels of the factor, which don't go away, even if the value does. For example:

```
x <- factor(letters[1:5])
x
# [1] a b c d e
# Levels: a b c d e
y <- x[1:3]
y
# [1] a b c
# Levels: a b c d e

table(x)
# x
# a b c d e 
# 1 1 1 1 1 
table(y)
# y
# a b c d e 
# 1 1 1 0 0
```

To get rid of the extra levels, set them manually, or just reset the factor:

```
y <- factor(y)
table(y)
# y
# a b c 
# 1 1 1
```

Comment: Or use `droplevels` (as in `table(droplevels(y))`) + 1.

Comment: Alistaire, you rock!  I did not know this about factors, THANK YOU!!